# What does filmic do exactly?

Tags: color-management

Filmic is great and both BLender Guru and Gleb alexandrov have made videos regarding Filmic. There is also a webpage for filmic by troy_sobotka https://sobotka.github.io/filmic-blender/ and some info in the Blender docs and on Stackexchange.

However nowhere is the way filmic works exactly described. It's always just "it desaturates with high intensity" or "it makes HDR images fit into the 0-1 range". Apart drom that most ofthe documentation including the webpyge ba troy_sobotka only talk about the Filmic addon, however Blender has Filmic already included by default but in an altered state.

Does anyone know what Filmic does in the background mathematically?
And is the Filmic implementation in Blender precisely documented anywhere?

Answer (score 4):

The best lay description is probably the [Filmic Log Whitepaper](http://filmicpro.com/FilmicLogWhitePaper.pdf)

Filmic Log is a transformation from a linear color space to a logarithmic color space, using the equation $y = 0.371 × (sqrt(t) + 0.28257 × ln(t) + 1.69542)$

Nothing is precisely documented in Blender.  The closest you get for Filmic would be to start at the [Color Management](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/color_management.html) manual page. It explains the overall workflow for filmic in the [Display Transforms](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/color_management.html#display-transforms) section.

For more precision you need to read the source code.

Comment: Unfortunately I actually don't have a coding background at all, so the source code really is only of limited use for me... But thanks anyways! I tried searching the file containing filmic transform but got lost in the tremendously huge Blender github repository. Could help me to find it? thAnks!