# Linear Interpolation Through Color Ramp Based on Angles

Tags: color, shader-nodes, interpolation

I'm coloring a sphere according to a color ramp where the angle from the south pole towards the north pole determines the color.

[image]

I want a linear interpolation through these colors, but it seems like the colors are getting squished at angles which are multiples of 60 degrees. How can I fix this?

To make this, I first captured the vector positioning attribute in geometry nodes and then passed it to the shader editor.
[image]

In the shader editor, I simply get the angle above the south pole using atan2 and I divide this angle by pi to get it in the range 0 thru 1. This 0 thru 1 number is then passed into a color ramp.
[image]

Maybe the colors aren't getting squished and I'm just misinterpreting because of my human eyes, but it really does look like the squishing is happening. I feel like an answer may reside in this post: [incorrect gradient in linear color ramp](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/154163/incorrect-gradient-in-linear-color-ramp) , but I can't make sense out of the formulas listed.

[image]

Comment: Nice answer from @lemon... BTW, you could get a 0-1 sweep around an axis with _Gradient > Radial_

Comment: Thanks.! Also added a mapping  beforehand with some Euler rotations to preserve my preferred orientation. Much simpler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is due to filmic color management.

[image]

With "filmic" on the left, and with "raw" on the right:

[image]

As indicated [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/264354/19156), the formula from raw color to filmic is the following:

$y = 0.371 × (sqrt(t) + 0.28257 × ln(t) + 1.69542)$

and corresponds to this curve number 1:

[image]

I don't think it's possible to "invert" the equation easily. But you can mimic the inverted curve using "RGB curves".

With "filmic":

[image]

Comment: Thanks lemon!  It's funny I was trying to discover that inverted equation last night by plotting points and matching a sin curve the closest I got was (sin(x*pi/2 - pi/2) + 1)^1.3105