# How to properly adjust the texture of the screen or text?

Tags: rendering, texturing, shaders

I'm trying to make a notebook mockup. But the textures for the screenshot look very bad and blurry. The textures are bad in both renders: in cycles and in eevee. The quality of render and of texture is about 4K. But the textures are still bad and black text looks ugly. I've tried to set closest interpolation, but the result is the same.

What I need to do to get good quality for texture?

Here is some quick screenshots to show the problem. The texts are really blurry and dim: [image][image]

But the white text looks good and it is bright:
[image]

Comment: That does not seem related, but I think this is the same issue (and the answer should do). https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/291255/linear-interpolation-through-color-ramp-based-on-angles/291269#291269 place the rgb curve between the image texture and the shader.

Comment: It doesn't help. The black text stays blurred

Comment: Could you share a texture?

Comment: The texture is very simple: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tpaZw9xM-E4mVgMAeRQ33pBEzbDEsmoi/view?usp=share_link

Comment: Well, not blury on my side. https://i.stack.imgur.com/BB3Gd.jpg but on the right image when color is not corrected, it is faded.

Comment: Can you show please your setting. I've tried to correct it with curve. The result is ok in the viewer, but in the render is still faded

Comment: Image as plane base setting plus the rgb curve https://i.stack.imgur.com/sXCZv.png

Comment: I've also tried to render it. Nothing is blurry.

Comment: Thank you! Can you show please the render result?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Tda3.jpg Corrected on the left, without correction on the right. And this one using "closest" on the textures: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9HJkX.jpg

Comment: Thank you. The result is interesting, but by this method colors look very different than in the source. The blue color is not blue more =(